# Kendo dropdown list sorted order

Tags: angular, sorting, kendo-ui

I have this kendo dropdown list in Angular how do I sort this list?

I dont see any sort param for kendo-dropdownlist on kendo website.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6pome-dfnigx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use orderBy ([documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/data-query/api/orderBy/)):

```typescript
public groupedData: GroupResult[] = groupBy(orderBy(this.source, [{ field: "name", dir: "asc" }]), [
  { field: "subcategory" }
]);
```

Fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6pome-w2dbsn